# addAll function is duplicating objects in List

Tags: java, android, list, join

My goal is to join two lists in one list, but the problem is that the objects of the first list duplicates twice, this the code below:

```
List<Image> unionList = new ArrayList<Image>();

      unionList.addAll(fromImageList);

       unionList.addAll(fromTagList);
```

so that the objects of fromImageList are joined twice.

Comment: How are `fromImageList` and `fromtagList` populated?  The code that you've shown won't duplicate any list elements, so I suspect that you either have duplicate elements in the lists that you're adding to `unionList`, or you've managed to assign a variable incorrectly, and are adding the same list twice.

Comment: @Jordan yes you are right, i check one list from the two lists and I found that their is a problem in it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want aggregate only unique images, then you should use Set

```
Set<Image> uniqueImages = new HashSet<>();

uniqueImages.addAll(fromImageList);

uniqueImages.addAll(fromTagList);

List<Image> unionList = new ArrayList<>(uniqueImages)
```

Comment: I'd caution @wisam to make sure that they're not losing data in this case, though.  They said that "the objects of fromImageList are joined twice", which makes me suspect that they're assigning two variables to point to the same list, which would be a larger underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

When `List<Image> unionList = new ArrayList<Image>();` is excecuted, an empty arrayList is created.

When `unionList.addAll(fromImageList);` is excecuted, all the images in fromImageList are added to unionList.

When `unionList.addAll(fromTagList);` is excecuted, all the images in fromTagList are added to unionList.

ArrayList doen't prevent duplication. If you want to prevent duplication, you have to use Set implementation like HashSet.

You can do like the following

```
Set<Image> uniqueImages = new HashSet<>();
uniqueImages.addAll(fromImageList);
uniqueImages.addAll(fromTagList);

List<Image> unionList = new ArrayList<>(uniqueImages)
```